# How to find date range in R

Tags: r

I have my dates as:

```
mydates <- c("2018-10-27", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-27", "2018-10-27", "2018-10-27", "2018-10-27", "2018-10-27", "2018-10-15", "2018-10-27", "2018-10-27")
```

I would like to determine the range of dates in days. For example, the range for mydates would be 25 days from `2018-10-02` to the latest date `2018-10-27`. How can we achieve this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Convert it into `date` and use `range` and `diff`

```
as.integer(diff(range(as.Date(mydates))))
#[1] 25
```

`range` gives `max` and `min` of the vector

```
range(as.Date(mydates))
#[1] "2018-10-02" "2018-10-27"
```

Answer (score 1):

We convert it to `Date` class with `as.Date`, get the `range` of those dates and find the `diff`erence

```
as.numeric(diff(range(as.Date(mydates))))
#[1] 25
```

---

Or another option is to `sort`, get the 1st and last dates, and take the difference

```
Reduce(`-`, as.Date(sort(mydates)[c(1, length(mydates))]))
```

---

It can be written in a tidier way as well

```
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
mydates %>% 
   ymd %>%
   range %>% 
   diff %>% 
   as.numeric
#[1] 25
```